# Get character array from config c#

Tags: c#

I want to get a set of character array like below from config and in the code need to set it as a List of characters. Can you please let know how to do that.

```
<add key="Replace" value="\t,\n,\r,\\"/>
```

In code I need to get this as

```
List<char> t = new List<char> { '\t', '\n', '\r', '\\' };
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class.  You may also want to look at the System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection class.  If you intend to store the string in your configuration as you show above, it would be helpful to know how to split a string on a given character, such as a comma.

Comment: Also, Vishnu, I did not vote down your question, and I see that the down-voters have not left a comment.  You will want to know that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but a coding assistance community.  Take a stab at what you need to do, then post again with what's not working for you.  You should find ample help here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the code for you, but here is an outline of what you have to do.

1) Read in the setting using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

2) Split the value based on the comma using using the Split function

3) Write a function to convert a string literal to a char (e.g. "\t" = '\t')

4) Assign to your List<>

Comment: Is it even possible to put \t,\n,\r into a configuration string that is XML-based?

Comment: @RobertHarvey you definitely can. I've tested a solution and it works

Comment: when i read its not coming as List<chars> also not really sure how we can set this chars like - \n,\t etc in the config.

Comment: @Vishnu - you would either have to write your own method to convert escape sequences to chars and call that, or store the ascii or hex value in the config and directly convert to a char.